# How do I differentiate $x^r$ where r is irrational?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Until r was a rational number, it was found that $rx^{r-1}$ was used in induction, inverse function theorem, and implicit function theorem, chain rule.
But if r is irrational, I can't think of a way. Now that I've learned how to organize the mean value in analysis, will I know if I study more or will it be possible with what I've learned so far?

DEFNITION: $x^r:=sup${$x^a|a<r$ and a is rational}

Comment: Have you defined the logarithm? If so take the log of both sides of $y=x^r$ and implicitly differentiate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is theorem which says that if $f_n$ is (continuously) differentiable and $f_n^\prime \rightarrow g$ uniformly, and if $f_n(x_0) $ converges to $f(x_0)$ for some value $x_0$, then $f$ is (continuously) differentiable with $g=f^\prime$.

If you happen to know this theorem you can get the derivative of $x^r$ by approximation (which is a good exercise, but, admittedly, a bit tedious, because you have to verify all the assumptions using a - at your stage of education - difficult definiton of $x^r$). Otherwise this is usually done with the help of the exponential function, once you know that $x^r = e^{r\ln(x)}$ and how to differentiate the exponential and the logarithm.